# The WSL CLI window disappears directly after it has opened -- how to fix that?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I use Docker and WSL2 with an Ubuntu 20.04 distro on Windows 10.

For running programs in linux and getting the GUI in Windows I installed [GWSL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/gwsl/9nl6kd1h33v3). Due to some troubles with it I uninstalled it and Ubuntu to set up all that again from scratch and resolve the issues.

Before I could start the WSL CLI window by opening the `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe` (either via the shortcut in the Windows Start or from the CMD / Power Shell / Git Bash). Now, when I start, the WSL command line window opens for less than a second and immediately disappears again.

**What might cause this behavior and how to fix it?**

---

**Additional infotmation**

```
> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

[image: WLS-Windows-Start]

Comment: I could see several possible reasons, but I'd need some more detail (remember to edit your question to include this) -- First, provide the output of `wsl -l -v`.  Second, how did you uninstall Ubuntu (there are at least four different ways)?  Third, did you rerun the `ubuntu.exe` or Ubuntu from the Start Menu after reinstalling to have it configure the instance with the default username, password, (and most importantly) filesystem?

Comment: Also, you mention running `wsl.exe` from the Start Menu.  Do you mean the Ubuntu store app?   The `wsl.exe` command never actually gets placed on the Start menu.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for your comment. I've just added the info you asked for to the question. I uninstalled Ubuntu multiple times: from the "Programs and Functions" and from the start menu -- and installed it again. Last time I could not uninstall Ubuntu completely (and could not install it again then) a,d tried to complete the installation by editing the registry. Later I got the app uninstalled. So maybe broke something in the registry, and it prevents now starting WSL from Windows Start. The configs of the username was always the same, the iflesystem has not been configured explicitely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your `wsl -l -v` output, it looks like the `docker-desktop-data` instance got set as the default when you uninstalled Ubuntu.  That's not actually a bootable instance, since it has no `/init` in it.

That *hopefully* will explain why the `wsl` command is exiting.  Just running `wsl.exe` (from PowerShell, CMD, or the Start Menu) is attempting to launch `docker-desktop-data` and then immediately exits.

You should be able to fix it by executing `wsl --set-default Ubuntu` from PowerShell or CMD.  If not, we can dig deeper.

Comment: Running `wsl --set-default Ubuntu` from PowerShell solved my issue with WSL restarting all the time when I was opening it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case, I didn't have the `Ubuntu` distribution.

So, I installed it, using this command:

```bash
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

Then I used the following command to set the `Ubuntu` distribution as default:

```bash
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

Other useful commands:

```
# To list all installed distributions
wsl --list --verbose
wsl -l -v

# To see the available distributions to install
wls --list --online
```